# Reliable styling for different screen size

Tags: css

I have a pop-up box, on left there is usual login forms - email/password, on the right - FB login button. I used divs with inline block display (mostly because i want to be border between usual log in form and FB button).
The issue is that I felt that something is not good (I'm quite unexperienced in CSS), and than I decided to try how it looks on another laptop (with screen a little bit smaller), and it is completely disaster - all is messed up.
Help me to refactor my styling. May be in that case it should be like table?

```
.sign_in {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 30%;
    left: 28%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: #c1ffc6;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 2%;
    width: 40%;
    height: 25%;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    z-index: 9999999;
    font-size: 14px;


}
.signs_form{
    margin-top: 5%;
    font-family: Arial,Liberation Sans,DejaVu Sans,sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    border-right-style: solid;
    padding-right: 10%;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #c1ffc6;


}
.fb_sign {

    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: 100%;
    margin-left: 10%;


}
#sign_in_fb {
    vertical-align: 100%;

}
```

it is extended ruby html file:

```
<div class = "sign_in" >
<div id="close"> <%= link_to('X','#', :id=>'close_sign_in_popup', :remote=>true)%> </div>
<%= form_tag sessions_path, :class=>'signs_form', :remote=>true do %>
    #so on
<span class="fb_sign">
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Any chance for jsfiddle? Also post relevant html

Comment: You need to post your HTML too.

Comment: Change % to px then you've got pretty the same on different screen sizes. If you want go further google for responsive design then you cover all devices. And I'm pretty sure that z-index in your case is useless. If you declare font-family for body element then all elements will use it so no need to repeat in other classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use media queries to get different styles depending the device width

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {

/*your css for these devices*/

}

@media (max-width: 767px) {

  /*your css for these devices*/

}
```